# How to get value of selectinput and show a variable data in another selectinput with shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I want to retrieve the selected value by the user, so i put this code in server.R inside the function

```
selected_value <- input$valtext
A <-Filter (catalog, gene_name == selected_value)
B <-select (A,snp)
```

valtext : is the id of my selectizeinput

then i want to show the snp correspondent of selected_value by the user 
(B) in another selectizeinput in "choices", but to do this i need to retrieve the variable B :

```
selectizeInput( 
  'snpvalue', 'Choisir le snp a visualiser :', choices = "" ,
  multiple = TRUE, options = list(maxItems = 2)
      )
```

My problem is i can not see B in the data, it seems nothing change !nothing execute, because if i will have my variable B, i can easily show it in my selectizeinput

Comment: You need to create the UI from the server side using `renderUI`.

Comment: @warmoverflow i do not understand you

Comment: my problem, it seems nothing execute in my function reactive, i mean i do not have yet my variable (B) to be able call it in my parameter (choices)

Comment: Your second selectizeinput is in ui.R, but you cannot use or see any results from server.R in ui.R (that is by design). To fix this, You need to creat a uiOutput in ui.R, then use renderUI in server.R to dynamically render your second selectizeinput

Comment: @warmoverflow , what should i write in uiOutput and renderUI ? could you give me the exactly code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ui.R`, replace your second `selectizeInput` with

```
uiOutput('snpselect')
```

In `server.R`, add

```
output$snpselect <- renderUI({
  selected_value <- input$valtext
  A <- Filter (catalog, gene_name == selected_value)
  B <- select (A,snp)
  selectizeInput( 
    'snpvalue', 'Choisir le snp a visualiser :', choices = B, multiple = TRUE, options = list(maxItems = 2)
  )
})
```

Comment: i tried to do what you gived to me, but i have got this error : object 'f' of mode 'function' was not found
?

Comment: Warning: Error in get: object 'f' of mode 'function' was not found
Stack trace (innermost first):
    87: get
    86: match.fun
    85: lapply
    84: unlist
    83: Filter
    82: renderUI [myapp.R#76]
    81: func
    80: origRenderFunc
    79: output$snpselect
     4: <Anonymous>
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1: print

Comment: It's probably that you have an object named `Filter` which collides with the function `Filter` but without your full code it's hard to tell.